# Python: removing outliers from a list. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python

the following code snippet is from one of my functions which is passed a list of numbers and is supposed to remove outliers (i.e. very large or very small numbers) from the list.

The code does not seem to work as intended, as the output confirms:

```
EXTREMA_CUTOFF_THRESHOLD=3.0

if list_values:    
    avg_val = sum(list_values)/float(len(list_values))
    print 'DEBUG: BEFORE:', min(list_values), max(list_values), avg_val
    list_values = [x for x in list_values if math.fabs(x - avg_val)/float(avg_val) < EXTREMA_CUTOFF_THRESHOLD]

    list_values_len = len(list_values)
    if (list_values_len > 0) and (min_sample_size > 0) and (list_values_len < min_sample_size):
        print 'DEBUG: Insufficient data for stats calculation for row'
    elif (list_values_len > 0):
        print 'DEBUG: AFTER:', min(list_values), max(list_values), avg_val
```

**Output:**

```
DEBUG: BEFORE: 11.0 302.0 113.897260274
DEBUG: AFTER: 11.0 302.0 113.897260274
DEBUG: BEFORE: 12.5 273.0 108.382352941
DEBUG: AFTER: 12.5 273.0 108.382352941
DEBUG: BEFORE: 2.5 245.5 69.9166666667
DEBUG: AFTER: 2.5 245.5 69.9166666667
DEBUG: BEFORE: 136.5 499.5 363.775
DEBUG: AFTER: 136.5 499.5 363.775
DEBUG: BEFORE: 39.5 422.5 166.035759097
DEBUG: AFTER: 39.5 422.5 166.035759097
DEBUG: BEFORE: 39.5 422.0 152.305007587
DEBUG: AFTER: 39.5 422.0 152.305007587
DEBUG: BEFORE: 20.5 331.0 84.41015625
DEBUG: AFTER: 20.5 331.0 84.41015625
DEBUG: BEFORE: 7.0 267.5 155.810126582
DEBUG: AFTER: 7.0 267.5 155.810126582
```

Why are the extreme values not being filtered out?

Comment: Can you give us an example for `list_values` for which the script doesn't do want you want it to do? For `list_values=[1, 1, 1, 1, 100000000]` it removes the "outlier".

Comment: (113-11) / 113 < 3. (302-113) / 113 < 3. Your threshold is not good. (nota : for a threshold > 1, small values always stay, in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working.  It's just that none of the extreme values are more than 3 times the average away from the average, which is what your algorithm implies

Comment: I used a trimmed mean, and changed the threshold value. Obvious after the fact ... :/

Comment: Do not just change the threshold value. The problem is that you are using the wrong equation. You should divide by the standard deviation (not the average!) as explained by the various answers here.

Answer (score 5):

One thing: you do not re-calculate the `avg_val` after filtering the list.

Another thing: have you played with your `EXTREMA_CUTOFF_THRESHOLD`? Maybe 3.0 does not filter anything from your test data set, but a lower value would.

A general comment: I'd work with `numpy` in this case and make use of the standard deviation (`numpy.std(dataarray)`) of the dataset for determining outliers (cf. @mgilson's comment for a specific method). A good resource regarding outlier detection seems to be this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier

Comment: +1 for adding a comment about standard deviation.

Comment: I am actually working with scipy to calculate stats on the sample. However, the outliers were resulting in 'nonsensical' values being printed for min and max.

Comment: In terms of numpy, you can do:  `x = arr[(x>(3*std-mean)) & (x<(3*std+mean))]`

Answer (score 1):

Note that the naive way of computing the average via `sum / len` loses you numerical precision. Furthermore, you probably want to also compute the standard deviation.

Your thresholding equation of

```
math.fabs(x - avg_val)/float(avg_val) < EXTREMA_CUTOFF_THRESHOLD
```

should probably be something like

```
math.fabs(x - avg_val)/float(   standard_deviation  ) < EXTREMA_CUTOFF_THRESHOLD
```

at least if you plan on using classic normal distribution assumptions (e.g 3 sigma outliers), which are defined in terms of **standard deviations**!

What threshold do you use? On your first data set, if you are using `3`, it is fairly simple to see that no values are larger than 455.58904109600002 or less than -227.79452054800001

(Note that using the **standard deviation** for normalization should fix this. Don't just blindly decrease your threshold.)

You are also computing the wrong length: `list_values_len = len(bid_values)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That was a typo. I have corrected the variable name.

Comment: Now try using the standard deviation!

Answer (score 1):

Your term `math.fabs(x - avg_val)/float(avg_val)` means "the distance of one datum to the mean in relation to the mean".  I don't think that this makes much sense.  Imagine a set of birth years, i. e. numbers all in the range 1920..2010.  To put the distance in relation to the absolute value of the mean makes not much sense.

So back to square one:  Consider a more decent rule to find out which elements you want to strip.  Other answers here refer to that already.

Comment: The values are prices. So the percentage deviation from the average should be a good enough rule to remove erroneous prices from the list.